# Php mysqli real escape string add back slashes

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a text field that stores a value in database. When I input inverted commas i.e **" "** or apostrophe i.e. **''** it automatically adds back slash to my string. How to remove back slashes or inverted commas and apostrophe?

```
<?php
if (empty($_POST['video_title'])) {
        $error[] = 'You must enter a video title';
    } else {
        $vid_title =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['video_title']);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Perhaps you have [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) enabled?

Comment: i dont know exactly about magic quotes enabled or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is happening because of magic quotes, you should [disable](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php), if you don't want to, you can run stripslashes()

such as

```
<?php
if (empty($_POST['video_title'])) {
        $error[] = 'You must enter a video title';
    } else {
        $vid_title =  mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['video_title']);
        $vid_title = stripslashes($vid_title);
    }
?>
```